# Python - Parents and Multithreading issues

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, python-multithreading

I am learning PyQT and Multithreading, and I think I need help here. In my code, I have a a class `Tool`, and a thread `TaskThread`. From the thread, I call the function `dummy_function` which perform a proccess being displayed in the GUI by a progress-bar.

When `dummy_function` finishes, I want to print a message in the GUI, by calling `self.outputText.setText("Hello")`. However, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'TaskThread' object has no attribute 'outputText'

Code:

```
import sys
import datetime
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# Link to GUI
qtCreatorFile = "GUInterface.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

def time_converter_to_unix(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    # Convert QTimeEdit to UNIX Timestamp (int, msec included), and then to float
    start_datetime_unix_int = start_datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch ()
    start_datetime_unix = (float(start_datetime_unix_int) / 1000)

    end_datetime_unix_int = end_datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch ()
    end_datetime_unix = (float(end_datetime_unix_int) / 1000)

    return start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix

def dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix): 
    # Dummy function, just to simulate a task. It takes parameters just for testing.
    result = start_datetime_unix * end_datetime_unix 

    # Pre-steps for mapping from one range to other (progress-bar)
    OldMax = 99999
    OldMin = 1
    NewMax = 100
    NewMin = 1

    OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin)
    NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin)    

    u = 1
    for i in range (OldMax):
        u = i*2

        OldValue = i
        print OldValue
        NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin
        print "NEW VALUE: ", NewValue

        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), NewValue)

    self.outputText.setText("Hello")

class Tool(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        # Setting-ip UI
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Button Action
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.onStart)

        # Progress Bar and Label. At the begining, the bar is at 0
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,100)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Waiting...")  

        ####################################
        #TEST: Thread for progress bar
        self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
        self.connect(self.myLongTask, QtCore.SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), self.onProgress)
        self.myLongTask.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)
        ####################################        

    def onStart(self):    

        self.progressBar.reset()
        self.resultLabel.setText("In progress...")        
        print "(onStart)In progress mode executed"

        print "(onStart)INITIALIZE THREAD"
        self.myLongTask.start()     
        print "(onStart)THREAD EXECUTED"

        self.myLongTask.start_dt = self.startTime.dateTime() # <----
        self.myLongTask.end_dt = self.endTime.dateTime()     # <----

    def onProgress(self, i):
        self.progressBar.setValue(i)        

    def onFinished(self):
        # Stop the pulsation when the thread has finished
        print "(onFinished) executed"
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
        self.progressBar.setValue(1)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Done")        

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):  
      taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):  
        # First, we read the times from the QDateTime elements in the interface      
        print "Getting times..."
        start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix = time_converter_to_unix(self.start_dt, self.end_dt)

        # Then, we put these values in my_function
        print "Executing function..."
        dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix) 

        # To finish, we execute onFinished.
        print "Finishing thread..."
        self.taskFinished.emit()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Tool()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The **first** thing I tried, it was to add the following line to my `onStart` function:

```
...
self.myLongTask.output_dt = self.outputText
...
```

Then, in the `TaskThread`, I change the call of `dummy_function` by:

```
...
dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix, self.output_dt) 
...
```

To finish, I change my dummy_function by adding this new parameter:

```
def dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix, output_text): 
    # Dummy function, just to simulate a task. It takes parameters just for testing.
    result = start_datetime_unix * end_datetime_unix 

    # Pre-steps for mapping from one range to other (progress-bar)
    OldMax = 99999
    OldMin = 1
    NewMax = 100
    NewMin = 1

    OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin)
    NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin)    

    u = 1
    for i in range (OldMax):
        u = i*2

        OldValue = i
        print OldValue
        NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin
        print "NEW VALUE: ", NewValue

        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), NewValue)

    output_text.setText("Hello")
```

Now, when it reaches the end, the program just closes showing the following error:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
>   (Parent is QTextDocument(0xf13a60), parent's thread is QThread(0xc6f180), current thread is TaskThread(0xee0740)

In order to try the program, I uplodaed the [GUInterface](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1siYGyHag9Qio3PUGvUrGXi9vufKDzdvJ), so you can try it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one you get is caused because `TaskThread` does not have `outputText` as an attribute, and your solution is in a certain way correct since it solves the first problem, but there is another problem, Qt prohibits the GUI from being updated directly from another thread generating that problem . Qt indicates that if you want to update the GUI with the information of other threads you must use signals or the `QMetaObject`, in this case I will solve it by creating a `signal` called `textChanged`, this will be connected to the `setText()` method of `outputText`.

On the other hand I see that you are using an old connection style:

```
self.connect(self.myLongTask, QtCore.SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), self.onProgress)
```

that style although you can still use it is no longer recommended, the best is use the [new syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

And finally the functions that are connected to the signals are called slots, so it is recommended to use the decorator `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(...)`, this method minimizes the consumption of resources.

```
import sys
import datetime
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# Link to GUI
qtCreatorFile = "GUInterface.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

def time_converter_to_unix(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    # Convert QTimeEdit to UNIX Timestamp (int, msec included), and then to float
    start_datetime_unix_int = start_datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch ()
    start_datetime_unix = (float(start_datetime_unix_int) / 1000)

    end_datetime_unix_int = end_datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch ()
    end_datetime_unix = (float(end_datetime_unix_int) / 1000)

    return start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix

def dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix): 
    # Dummy function, just to simulate a task. It takes parameters just for testing.
    result = start_datetime_unix * end_datetime_unix 

    # Pre-steps for mapping from one range to other (progress-bar)
    OldMax = 99999
    OldMin = 1
    NewMax = 100
    NewMin = 1

    OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin)
    NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin)    

    u = 1
    for i in range (OldMax):
        u = i*2

        OldValue = i
        print(OldValue)
        NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin
        print("NEW VALUE: ", NewValue)

        self.cpuValueChanged.emit(NewValue)

    self.textChanged.emit("Hello")

class Tool(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        # Setting-ip UI
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Button Action
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.onStart)

        # Progress Bar and Label. At the begining, the bar is at 0
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,100)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Waiting...")  

        ####################################
        #TEST: Thread for progress bar
        self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
        self.myLongTask.cpuValueChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)
        self.myLongTask.textChanged.connect(self.outputText.setText)
        self.myLongTask.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)
        ####################################        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onStart(self):    
        self.progressBar.reset()
        self.resultLabel.setText("In progress...")        
        print("(onStart)In progress mode executed")

        print("(onStart)INITIALIZE THREAD")
        self.myLongTask.start()     
        print("(onStart)THREAD EXECUTED")

        self.myLongTask.start_dt = self.startTime.dateTime() # <----
        self.myLongTask.end_dt = self.endTime.dateTime()     # <----     

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onFinished(self):
        # Stop the pulsation when the thread has finished
        print("(onFinished) executed")
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
        self.progressBar.setValue(1)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Done")        

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    cpuValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)  
    taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):  
        # First, we read the times from the QDateTime elements in the interface      
        print("Getting times...")
        start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix = time_converter_to_unix(self.start_dt, self.end_dt)

        # Then, we put these values in my_function
        print("Executing function...")
        dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix) 

        # To finish, we execute onFinished.
        print("Finishing thread...")
        self.taskFinished.emit()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Tool()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Great and fast answer. I think I understand a little bit better now some concepts. Thank you!